# C# PCAP.NET how to send a valid TCP request?

Tags: c#, tcp, pcap.net

I wil try using PCAP.NET to send TCP Request from my computer to my server but i don't see request into the server?

[Send from my PC and showing in Wireshare here](http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7351/10939864076_1f0dd03192_c.jpg)

But can't see this TCP Request on my server, please help.

here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using PcapDotNet.Base;
using PcapDotNet.Core;
using PcapDotNet.Packets;
using PcapDotNet.Packets.Arp;
using PcapDotNet.Packets.Dns;
using PcapDotNet.Packets.Ethernet;
using PcapDotNet.Packets.Gre;
using PcapDotNet.Packets.Http;
using PcapDotNet.Packets.Icmp;
using PcapDotNet.Packets.Igmp;
using PcapDotNet.Packets.IpV4;
using PcapDotNet.Packets.Transport;
using System.Text;

namespace PcapTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Retrieve the device list from the local machine
            IList<LivePacketDevice> allDevices = LivePacketDevice.AllLocalMachine;

            if (allDevices.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No interfaces found! Make sure WinPcap is installed.");
                return;
            }

            // Print the list
            for (int i = 0; i != allDevices.Count; ++i)
            {
                LivePacketDevice device = allDevices[i];
                Console.Write(String.Format("{0}. {1}", (i + 1), device.Name));
                if (device.Description != null)
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format(" ({0})", device.Description));
                else
                    Console.WriteLine(" (No description available)");
            }

            int deviceIndex = 0;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Enter the interface number (1-{0}):", allDevices.Count));
                string deviceIndexString = Console.ReadLine();
                if (!int.TryParse(deviceIndexString, out deviceIndex) ||
                    deviceIndex < 1 || deviceIndex > allDevices.Count)
                {
                    deviceIndex = 0;
                }
            } while (deviceIndex == 0);

            // Take the selected adapter
            PacketDevice selectedDevice = allDevices[deviceIndex - 1];

            // Open the output device
            using (PacketCommunicator communicator = selectedDevice.Open())
            {
                communicator.SendPacket(BuildTcpPacket());
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static Packet BuildTcpPacket()
        {
            EthernetLayer ethernetLayer =
                new EthernetLayer
                {
                    Source = new MacAddress("00:25:22:50:ef:74"),
                    Destination = new MacAddress("02:02:02:02:02:02"),
                    EtherType = EthernetType.None, // Will be filled automatically.
                };

            IpV4Layer ipV4Layer =
                new IpV4Layer
                {
                    Source = new IpV4Address("192.168.1.203"), // <- this is my LAN IP ADDRESS IS TRUE??
                    CurrentDestination = new IpV4Address("113.23.x.x"), // <-- THIS IS MY SERVER IPADDESS??
                    Fragmentation = IpV4Fragmentation.None,
                    HeaderChecksum = null, // Will be filled automatically.
                    Identification = 64,
                    Options = IpV4Options.None,
                    Protocol = null, // Will be filled automatically.
                    Ttl = 64,
                    TypeOfService = 0,
                };

            TcpLayer tcpLayer =
                new TcpLayer
                {
                    SourcePort = 9509,
                    DestinationPort = 80,
                    Checksum = null, // Will be filled automatically.
                    SequenceNumber = 100,
                    AcknowledgmentNumber = 50,
                    ControlBits = TcpControlBits.Acknowledgment,
                    Window = 100,
                    UrgentPointer = 0,
                    Options = TcpOptions.None,
                };

            PayloadLayer payloadLayer =
                new PayloadLayer
                {
                    Data = new Datagram(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("hello world")),
                };

            PacketBuilder builder = new PacketBuilder(ethernetLayer, ipV4Layer, tcpLayer);

            return builder.Build(DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The payLoadLayer isn't used? So what data is it sending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see that you are using your payloadLayer in the PacketBuilder.

According to a sample from Pcat.net, the payload should be included in the PacketBuilder constructor.

```
PacketBuilder builder = new PacketBuilder(ethernetLayer, ipV4Layer, tcpLayer, payloadLayer);
```

[Tutorial sending packets](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pcap.Net%20Tutorial%20-%20Sending%20Packets)

Comment: i will edit done and trying to send a valid TCP Request but still can't see this request on my server :( i will work like Turorial but same result

Comment: Thanks, i will capture a valid TCP request and setting pcap and work fine, thanks so much :-)