# How to interpret wireshark messages and send them with c#

Tags: c#, wireshark, pcap, projector

I have a Barco projector that I would like to remote control myself.

Barco has his own [tool](http://www.barco.com/en/products-solutions/display-management-software/all-in-one-remote-projector-management-software.aspx#!downloads) to do this, but is fully written in java.

When I catch the data being sent to swith to HDMI source with wireshark I get the following:

```
0000   00 0d 0a 01 2a bc d8 d3 85 95 91 57 08 00 45 00  ....*......W..E.
0010   00 31 51 72 40 00 80 06 00 00 0a 00 00 0d 0a 00  .1Qr@...........
0020   00 3e ef e1 04 01 c2 67 14 b8 9e da c6 b2 50 18  .>.....g......P.
0030   01 00 14 6e 00 00 3a 49 48 44 4d 20 31 20 0d     ...n..:IHDM 1 .


0000   00 0d 0a 01 2a bc d8 d3 85 95 91 57 08 00 45 00  ....*......W..E.
0010   00 28 51 73 40 00 80 06 00 00 0a 00 00 0d 0a 00  .(Qs@...........
0020   00 3e ef e1 04 01 c2 67 14 c1 9e da c6 c4 50 10  .>.....g......P.
0030   01 00 14 65 00 00                                ...e..
```

And to switch back to DVI I get:

```
0000   00 0d 0a 01 2a bc d8 d3 85 95 91 57 08 00 45 00  ....*......W..E.
0010   00 31 53 1e 40 00 80 06 00 00 0a 00 00 0d 0a 00  .1S.@...........
0020   00 3e ef e1 04 01 c2 67 14 c1 9e da c6 c4 50 18  .>.....g......P.
0030   01 00 14 6e 00 00 3a 49 44 56 49 20 31 20 0d     ...n..:IDVI 1 .


0000   00 0d 0a 01 2a bc d8 d3 85 95 91 57 08 00 45 00  ....*......W..E.
0010   00 28 53 20 40 00 80 06 00 00 0a 00 00 0d 0a 00  .(S @...........
0020   00 3e ef e1 04 01 c2 67 14 ca 9e da c6 d6 50 10  .>.....g......P.
0030   00 ff 14 65 00 00                                ...e..
```

I've tried some things out in c#, but with little success:

```
IPAddress beamerIP = new IPAddress(IpToBin("!!Beamer IP!!"));
IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(beamerIP, 1025);
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

socket.Connect(ip);
Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to " + socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(":IDVI 1 .");
byte[] dvi = new byte[] { 0x3a, 0x49, 0x44, 0x56, 0x49, 0x20, 0x31, 0x20, 0x0d };
byte[] hdmi = new byte[] { 0x3a, 0x49, 0x48, 0x44, 0x4d, 0x20, 0x31, 0x20, 0x0d };

int bytesSent = socket.Send(dvi);
Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes.", bytesSent);

socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
socket.Close();
```

I've also tried sending with PCAP.NET like in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20065248/c-sharp-pcap-net-how-to-send-a-valid-tcp-request), but with little success.

Am I doing something wrong or is there another approach to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was almost there. This is the code that worked for me:

```
// Data buffer for incoming data.
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
// Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.
IPAddress beamerIP = new IPAddress(IpToBin("!!Beamer IP!!"));
IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(beamerIP, 1025);
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
socket.Connect(ip);
// Send the data through the socket.
int bytesSent = socket.Send(message); //message => DVI = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(":IDVI 1 \r") || HDMI = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(":IHDM 1 \r")
// Receive the response from the remote device.
int bytesRec = socket.Receive(bytes);
// Release the socket.
socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
socket.Close();
```